# Qt5.9.1 QMYSQL driver won't load

Tags: mysql, qt, qt5

I already tried to fix it but nothing works... Here is a list of what i already did (I am a total beginner in linux so i might have failed to execute the solutions...)

1. I did compile the source with `sudo ./configure -sql-mysql` followed by `sudo make` and `sudo make install` in the `/opt/Qt/5.9.1/src/` and the result of this is `/usr/Qt-5.9.1/` being created and has files in it including `plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so
2. I installed (they were already) `mysql-server, mysql-server-5.7, mysql-client, mysql-client-5.7`. The MySQL version running for my apache server is 5.7
3. I added variables in the `.pro` file  `QT += sql`, `QTPLUGIN += qsqlmysql`, `CONFIG += c++11`, `INCLUDEPATH += /usr/include/mysql \
               /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/plugins/sqldrivers \
               /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1 \
               /usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/lib`, `LIBS+=-L/usr/lib -lmysqlclient_r`, `INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/local/Qt-5.9.1/plugins/sqldrivers/libqsqlmysql.so` but when i do `cd /usr/bin` followed by `-lmysqlclient_r` i get a command not found error.
4. I also did something related with `ln` command but i cannot find the links i found the answers on so im not sure about what it did exactly

I do not know if it has importance but my ide is set with Qt 5.9.1 and uses qmake for version 5.9.1 but i did download some qt 4 stuff with apt so when i do `qmake -v` i have version 5.5.1 in my command line.

I thought about downloading the 30days trial commercial version to get the driver already compiled but im not sure if when the trial will expire i will still be able to use the `QMYSQL` driver.

`/usr/lib$ ls | grep sql
libmysqlclient_r.so
libmysqlclient_r.so.18
libmysqlpp.so.3
libmysqlpp.so.3.2.2
libsqlite.so.0
libsqlite.so.0.8.6
mysql`

The following are list of packages i installed

`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep qt
appmenu-qt:amd64                install
appmenu-qt5                 install
libaccounts-qt5-1:amd64             install
libdbusmenu-qt2:amd64               install
libdbusmenu-qt5:amd64               install
libgsettings-qt1:amd64              install
liboxideqt-qmlplugin:amd64          install
liboxideqtcore0:amd64               install
liboxideqtquick0:amd64              install
libqt4-dbus:amd64               install
libqt4-declarative:amd64            install
libqt4-designer:amd64               install
libqt4-dev                  install
libqt4-dev-bin                  install
libqt4-help:amd64               install
libqt4-network:amd64                install
libqt4-opengl:amd64             install
libqt4-opengl-dev               install
libqt4-qt3support:amd64             install
libqt4-script:amd64             install
libqt4-scripttools:amd64            install
libqt4-sql:amd64                install
libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64              install
libqt4-sql-sqlite:amd64             install
libqt4-svg:amd64                install
libqt4-test:amd64               install
libqt4-xml:amd64                install
libqt4-xmlpatterns:amd64            install
libqt5concurrent5:amd64             install
libqt5core5a:amd64              install
libqt5dbus5:amd64               install
libqt5feedback5:amd64               install
libqt5gui5:amd64                install
libqt5multimedia5:amd64             install
libqt5network5:amd64                install
libqt5opengl5:amd64             install
libqt5opengl5-dev:amd64             install
libqt5organizer5:amd64              install
libqt5positioning5:amd64            install
libqt5printsupport5:amd64           install
libqt5qml5:amd64                install
libqt5quick5:amd64              install
libqt5quicktest5:amd64              install
libqt5sql5:amd64                install
libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64              install
libqt5sql5-sqlite:amd64             install
libqt5svg5:amd64                install
libqt5test5:amd64               install
libqt5webkit5:amd64             install
libqt5widgets5:amd64                install
libqt5xml5:amd64                install
libqtcore4:amd64                install
libqtdbus4:amd64                install
libqtgui4:amd64                 install
libsignon-qt5-1:amd64               install
libunity-action-qt1:amd64           install
oxideqt-codecs:amd64                install
qml-module-qt-labs-folderlistmodel:amd64    install
qml-module-qt-labs-settings:amd64       install
qml-module-qtfeedback:amd64         install
qml-module-qtgraphicaleffects:amd64     install
qml-module-qtquick-layouts:amd64        install
qml-module-qtquick-window2:amd64        install
qml-module-qtquick2:amd64           install
qml-module-qttest:amd64             install
qt-at-spi:amd64                 install
qt4-linguist-tools              install
qt4-qmake                   install
qt5-default:amd64               install
qt5-qmake:amd64                 install
qt5-qmake-arm-linux-gnueabihf:amd64     install
qtbase5-dev:amd64               install
qtbase5-dev-tools               install
qtchooser                   install
qtcore4-l10n                    install
qtdeclarative5-accounts-plugin:amd64        install
qtdeclarative5-dev-tools            install
qtdeclarative5-qtquick2-plugin:amd64        install
qtdeclarative5-test-plugin:amd64        install
qtdeclarative5-ubuntu-ui-toolkit-plugin     install
qtdeclarative5-unity-action-plugin:amd64    install
qttranslations5-l10n                install
sni-qt:amd64                    install`

---

`sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
dbconfig-mysql                  install
libmysql++3v5                   install
libmysql-java                   install
libmysqlclient-dev              install
libmysqlclient16:amd64              install
libmysqlclient20:amd64              install
libqt4-sql-mysql:amd64              install
libqt5sql5-mysql:amd64              install
mysql-apt-config                install
mysql-client                    install
mysql-client-5.7                install
mysql-client-core-5.7               install
mysql-common                    install
mysql-server                    install
mysql-server-5.7                install
mysql-server-core-5.7               install
php-mysql                   install
php7.0-mysql                    install`

Comment: I can not tell from what you posted, could be most anything. Any error message ? FWIW support for custom compiled applications is going to be limited at best.

Comment: The open source version of Qt is available to download "ready to go" [here](https://info.qt.io/download-qt-for-application-development). The Qt documentation also has [SQL examples](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-sql.html) that should help you get started.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this on? What error message? Can you also please format your question better? If you're using a custom Qt built from source, then the list of `dpkg --get-selections` output is not particularly useful. BTW, Ubuntu 17.10 already comes with Qt 5.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem and some Google research and intuition finally solved it.
Using Qt5.9.1 and Ubuntu 17.10

First, check if the error of `libmysqlclient.so.18 => not found` is present

```
    :~/Qt5.9.1/5.9.1/gcc_64/plugins/sqldrivers$ ldd libqsqlmysql.so
```

Second, search where is libmysqlclient

```
    :/$ locate libmysqlclient
```

Third, go to the folder where libmysqlclient is present and there make the link

```
    :/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu$ sudo ln -s libmysqlclient.so.20 libmysqlclient.so.18
```

and check the link made before with

```
    ls -alh | grep libmysql
```

At that moment, none of those solved for me, and i decided to look further in synaptic packages, and realize that `libqt5sql5-mysql` version 5.9.1 was not installed, so installing it solved the problem but i still have a message when doing ldd

> ./libqsqlmysql.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmysqlclient.so.18: version `libmysqlclient_18' not found (required by ./libqsqlmysql.so)

after that, found some links that guide me to a real solution, here are them, if you wanna know whats happening

i downloaded the library stated in the third link and worked like a charm. hope it helps!

https://www.unix.com/unix-for-advanced-and-expert-users/107611-difference-between-libsqlclient-so-libsqlclient_r-so.html

http://www.tango-controls.org/community/forum/c/general/installation/ubuntu-1604-problem-installing-from-source-code-libmysqlclient-replaces-libmysqlclient_r/

https://superuser.com/questions/1101426/installing-libmysqlclient18-on-ubuntu-16-04?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa&newreg=9c558283c488461aaf597ef1132e4ca0